# Mysql substring function - How to select string with varying lengths

Tags: mysql, substring

[image]
As you can see from the underlined strings in the image, I'd like to select all strings in each column from a table that begin with an "i" and ends with a "g". I've read about mysql substring function but haven't found one explaining how to select strings with varying lengths. Thanks.

Honestly I don't know where to begin, I haven't found anything on substrings that will lead me the right way

Comment: ```SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '"', 2), '/', -1)```

Comment: You're awesome Akina, works exactly how I wanted it. Thank you.

Comment: Akina, your answer works perfectly but could you give an explanation to the syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index - study carefully.